# Regular Expression to find a Tag (preg_replace_callback)

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need to find all occurrences of a Tag for a WP-Plugin.

```
<wpg3>10|300|defaultTemplate|eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9</wpg3>
```

There are serval possible Versions of the tag (,,, ...) but start and end do match. The Groups are optional: Should mean, that there could be none or one, or two or three "|", which separate the Options.

**My problem:** if there is only one Tag in my search-string everything will work as expected.
But if I add a second tag to my string , the callback is only called once, instead of once per Tag. There must be something missing at the Beginning or in the end.
The Regexp just fails using multiple tags if the **last Argument** (features) is missing.

```
  $return = preg_replace_callback('/<wpg[23](?P<unused>id)?>(?P<uri_or_id>[^\|]*)[\|]?(?P<width>[^\|]*)[\|]?(?P<template>[^\|]*)[\|]?(?P<features>[^\|]*)<\/wpg[23](?P<unused2>id)?>/i', array( $this, 'wpg3_content' ), $content );
```

I taking the example above I wanna get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10|300|defaultTemplate|eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9
    [unused] =>
    [1] => 
    [uri_or_id] => 10
    [2] => 10
    [width] => 300
    [3] => 300
    [template] => defaultTemplate
    [4] => defaultTemplate
    [features] => eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9
    [5] => eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9
)
```

Comment: Can there be `|` separators without values between them? By tag, you mean `<wpg3>`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do a preg_match_all on tags first of all

```
preg_match_all("/<([^>]*)?>/",$in, $out);
```

then loop through the $out array, where you should have the tag name and content.

if the tag matches what you want then

```
explode($out[2],"|")
```

or are you looking to do everything in your regex?

Comment: Basically I do a :
if(false === stripos($content, '<wpg') )
to make it faster. But maybe it is a good idea to first look for all tags, then take care for the content.

Answer (score 0):

Once you answer my comment above, I might have something more precise. Here is what I have so far. I made it in Python because it was easier for me, but you get the idea.

Here is my regex:

```
regex = re.compile('''
    <(?P<tag>wpg[23])(?P<unused>id)?>
   (?:
      (?P<uri_or_id>[^\|<]+)
       (?:
           \|(?P<width>[^\|<]+)
           (?:
              \|(?P<template>[^\|<]+)
              (?:
                 \|(?P<features>[^\|<]+)
               )?
            )?
        )?
    )?</(?P=tag)(?P<unused2>id)?>''', re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE)
```

Each text in the options is mandatory, but optional non-matching groups ensure that options are indeed optional. I also use a look-behind expression `(?P=tag)` to be sure that the closing tag matches the opening tag. I protected the matches a bit more than `[^\|]` with `[^\|>]` to prevent your multi-tag issues.

My test strings:

```
# Your example
>>> text
'<wpg3>10|300|defaultTemplate|eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9</wpg3>'

# Options should be, well, optional
>>> text2
'<wpg3>10|300|defaultTemplate</wpg3>'

# These two should fail if I understood properly    
>>> text3
'<wpg3>10|300|defaultTemplate|</wpg3>'
>>> text4
'<wpg3>10|300||</wpg3>'

# Now with more than one tag
>>> text5
'<wpg3>10|300|defaultTemplate|eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9</wpg3><wpg3>25|35|hello|world</wpg3>'
>>> text6
'<wpg3>10|300|defaultTemplate|eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9</wpg3><wpg2>25|35|hello|world</wpg2>'

# This should fail because tags mismatch
>>> text7
'<wpg3>10|300|defaultTemplate|eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9</wpg2>'
```

And here are the tests:

```
# Parses as expected
>>> regex.match(text).groups()
('wpg3', None, '10', '300', 'defaultTemplate', 'eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9', None)
>>> regex.match(text2).groups()
('wpg3', None, '10', '300', 'defaultTemplate', None, None)

# These two fail as expected
>>> regex.match(text3)
>>> regex.match(text4)

# Multi-tags now
>>> for m in regex.finditer(text5):
...    m.groups()
... 
('wpg3', None, '10', '300', 'defaultTemplate', 'eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9', None)
('wpg3', None, '25', '35', 'hello', 'world', None)
>>> for m in regex.finditer(text6):
...    m.groups()
... 
('wpg3', None, '10', '300', 'defaultTemplate', 'eyJhbGlnbiI6ImFsaWdubGVmdCJ9', None)
('wpg2', None, '25', '35', 'hello', 'world', None)

# The last one fails (tag mismatch)
>>> regex.match(text7)
```

Does that correspond to what you need?

Comment: How can I make a preg_replace string out of your pattern? It looks like you got what I need, but I got a "unknown modifyer "(" error :?

Maybe one thing: I need to match "<wpg3>, <wpg2> and <wpg2id>"-Tags in upper/lower-case at least. I don't care if I would match wpg3id too.

Comment: FINALLY:
 $return = preg_replace_callback('/<wpg[23](id)?>([^>]*)?<\/wpg[23](id)?>/i', array( $this, 'wpg3_content' ), $content );
and
explode("|", $g3_tag[0]) did it, according to your first proposal 
:D
THANKS!

Comment: @digitaldonkey: Glad it works. Please mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question :-)